# Read Content From Flickr in IPhone

Tags: iphone

I want to read all data from the following URL.

http://m.flickr.com/#/photos/westconn/

1. I want to read Image URL.
2. I want to read Title.
3. I want to read Updated Time.

Does anyone have any idea, sample application or sample URL links?

Comment: (This is too broad for Stack Overflow, and may even have been too broad at the time it was posted. If you are able to agree with the close reason, please do so.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think flickr would prefer it if you used the API they provide. There are a number of wrappers all ready written for you e.g. https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr

The alternative "screen scraping" approach is to use NSURLConnection to fetch the data, either synchronbously or asynchronously, and then decode the HTML. I recommend looking at this link for how to deal with HTML http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html